# EC2 instance from VScode

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I could not connect again my EC2 instance from VScode .Yestedy I connected with my remote computer but today , I get error.Cannot connect with host.Can anybody help me please?

Comment: How do you "connect" to the EC2 instance? What is the error you receive? Please Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: 0

Do you have a public IP linked to this EC2 ? Are you using the same computer

Answer (score 0):

Check the IP addresses.

This is common because new AWS users don't realize the IP can change after stopping the EC2 and restarting, unless you assign an Elastic IP address.

So if you did not use an Elastic IP, and you have stopped and started the server, the IP would have changed.

However to properly assist you you will need to post more details like the error you saw and the settings of the EC2 instance.